# Partial view/RenderAction returns 404 on model validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, renderaction

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 site where I need to show some account-related stats in the sidebar

I have a RenderAction in the layout i.e.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetStats", "MyController"); }
```

and the action method in MyController returns some text

```
  [HttpGet]
   public ContentResult GetStats()
   {
    ... snip (get stats from cache/db as the case may be)....
    return Content(String.Format("Your stats: {0}", stats));
   }
```

which works fine under normal circumstances.

However, say the view contains a form, and if a server-side model validation error is thrown, then the the render action returns a 404 view embedded where the stats should be. The rest of the page shows up fine, with the correct validation message etc.

I also tried using a regular partial view instead of a ContentResult with the same results.

Comment: Found the problem - adding it as a comment so that I can kick myself if I do this again. The issue was that I had a [HttpGet] on the controller action, which means that naturally it won't work when a form is submitted i.e. a POST.

Comment: You should post it as an answer.